# selenium grid parallel execution on the same browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I'm using selenium-grid, and want to how to start my tests in parallel on the same browser, for example: Chrome

The problem is, Chrome keeps opening  only one instance util the first test is finished, and then start the next test.

Please help me :)

```
public WebDriver createDriverGrid() throws MalformedURLException {
        String hubUrl = "http://localhost:4446/wd/hub";
        ChromeOptions capabilities = new ChromeOptions();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");
        driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), capabilities));
        return driver.get();
    }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="GoogleTestSuite" verbose="2" parallel="tests" thread-count="2" preserve-order="true">


    <test name="GoogleTest-CH" parallel="true">
    <!--<parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>-->
     <classes>
        <class name="com.herokuapp.theinternet.tests.GoogleTests" />
     </classes>
   </test>

</suite>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="PositiveTestSuite" verbose="2" parallel="tests" thread-count="2" preserve-order="true">
    <test name="PositiveTest-CH" parallel="true">
     <classes>
        <class name="com.herokuapp.theinternet.tests.PositiveTests" />
         <!--<class name="com.herokuapp.theinternet.tests.PositiveTests" />-->
     </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is `createDriverGrid` method? is it part of `@BeforeClass`?

Comment: It's a part of @BeforeMethod.

```

@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
 protected void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
  // Create Driver
  BrowserDriverFactory factory = new BrowserDriverFactory();
  setCurrentThreadName();
  driver = factory.createDriverGrid();
  // maximize browser window
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
 }

```

Comment: Also want to know if you have enough nodes to run the parallel scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start the test in parallel executing then you write a twice of your test method. As per your TestNG.xml, you have to write **parallel="tests" thread-count="2"** that means there has two test method which we want to execute parallelly.

Kindly replace your xml with below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="PositiveTestSuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

    <test name="PositiveTest-CH">
     <classes>
        <class name="com.herokuapp.theinternet.tests.PositiveTests" />
     </classes>
   </test>

   <test name="PositiveTest-CH1">
     <classes>
        <class name="com.herokuapp.theinternet.tests.PositiveTests" />
     </classes>
   </test>

</suite>
```

Try this it will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using jenkins pipelines, without having to modify your source code

Comment: how can we do this?